# RAID + LUKS + LVM + BCACHE + BTRFS

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lvm, btrfs, luks

I want build new structure for my data store (NAS - Ubuntu). Data storage will be 4TB at first. Then up to 8TB.

My old structure is simple:

`RAID 1 -> LUKS -> FS`

I need some wishes to new structure:

1. Save data (RAID 1 or 10).
2. Encryption.
3. Cache SSD + RAID (HDD) and file system with CoW to save data if cache will be broken.
4. Fast snapshots.
5. Flexibility to manage volumes.

I don't use LVM, BCACHE, BTRFS before. But IMHO it may suit me.

I'm thinking about this chain:

`RAID -> LUKS -> LVM -> BCACHE -> BTRFS`

Please tell me is this structure optimally? Is it the best variant for my tasks?

Comment: Why do you need LVM and RAID? BTRFS supports redundancy *and* subvolumes.

Comment: @vidarlo I believe that my question was closed incorrectly. But because I have little reputation, I could not open it and get an answer to my question.

Comment: @vidarlo I'm not entirely sure if BTRFS is stable and also performs RAID functionality. That's why I decided to use mdadm. Maybe I'm wrong so I'm asking the community tell me the where I can found trouble, tell me way whats read or something else.

Comment: @vidarlo I see. I think this one rules on whole StackExchange. Thanks for the explanation. Unlike the previous member of the community, you can clearly explained my mistake. I will delete the post in a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143095/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-jo-k).